# Magento 2 error upon setup:upgrade command

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extensions, setup-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a Magento 2 extension. When I run **`setup:upgrade`**,

I get the following error,

```
Upgrading data.. No such entity with cartId = 356670
```

How can I debug where exactly this error is happening? Is there any sort of log file created by **`setup:upgrade`** that will help me identify what SQL query is causing this error?

Answer (score 3):

**Upgrading data.. No such entity with cartId = 356670**.

Please check in your Database in cart table there was a record with id **356670**, and many other id there, this type of id is deleted but still in the database as record.
So you can first delete it,it solved error..Many Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Try to run below SQL directly to DB.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `store_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Make sure take backup !!

Comment: Already tried that, no go

Answer (score 2):

What Magento 2 version do you have ? 
Check this file

> vendor/magento/module-quote//Model/QuoteRepository.php
>   replace

```
 $quote = $this->loadQuote('load', 'cartId', $cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
```

with

```
    $quote = $this->loadQuote('loadByIdWithoutStore', 'cartId', $cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
```

It will look like something like :

```
public function get($cartId, array $sharedStoreIds = [])
{
    if (!isset($this->quotesById[$cartId])) {
        $quote = $this->loadQuote('loadByIdWithoutStore', 'cartId', $cartId, $sharedStoreIds);
        $this->getLoadHandler()->load($quote);
        $this->quotesById[$cartId] = $quote;
    }
    return $this->quotesById[$cartId];
}
```

Try again running the commands.

Comment: It's Magento 2.2.5